# AWS CodeDeploy error when trying to deploy python docker application in EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, devops, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy docker application, I am getting following error in `Application Start` phase:

> [stderr]unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in
> Dockerfile path: lstat /opt/codedeploy-agent/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory

My appspec.yml file is as follows:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/kill_container.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_container.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
```

I have tried setting different destinations, as follows:

> destination: /
>
> destination: /home/ec2-user/Deployment

None of the above works for me.

My kill_container.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
echo "Stopping and removing the running container========"
docker rm -f python-api-docker || true
```

My install_dependencies.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
echo "====================================================="
echo $PWD
pwd
ls
```

My start_container.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting container==="
set -e
echo $PWD
pwd
ls
docker build -t python-api-docker .
docker run -p 5000:5000 python-api-docker
```

The docker file is as follows:
FROM python:3.9-alpine

```
EXPOSE 5000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "api:app"]
```

I am attaching the error output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue is with missing Dockerfile, yet you haven't showed your deployment archive structure nor a Dockerfile.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the Dockerfile and its working properly in localhost

Comment: You can try by modifying your start_container.sh from `docker build -t python-api-docker .` to `docker build -t python-api-docker ./<folder in which dockerfile present>`